# Getting head to display all but the last line of a file: command substitution and standard I/O redirection

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

I have been trying to get the `head` utility to display all but the last line of standard input. The actual code that I needed is something along the lines of `cat myfile.txt | head -n $(($(wc -l)-1))`. But that didn't work. I'm doing this on Darwin/OS X which doesn't have the nice semantics of `head -n -1` that would have gotten me similar output.

None of these variations work either.

```
cat myfile.txt | head -n $(wc -l | sed -E -e 's/\s//g')
echo "hello" | head -n $(wc -l | sed -E -e 's/\s//g')
```

I tested out more variations and in particular found this to work:

```
cat <<EOF | echo $(($(wc -l)-1))
>Hola
>Raul
>Como Esta
>Bueno?
>EOF
3
```

Here's something simpler that also works.

```
echo "hello world" | echo $(($(wc -w)+10))
```

This one understandably gives me an illegal line count error. But it at least tells me that the `head` program is not consuming the standard input before passing stuff on to the subshell/command substitution, a remote possibility, but one that I wanted to rule out anyway.

```
echo "hello" | head -n $(cat && echo 1)
```

What explains the behavior of `head` and `wc` and their interaction through subshells here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`head` is the wrong tool.  If you want to see all but the last line, use:

```
sed \$d
```

The reason that

```
# Sample of incorrect code:
echo "hello" | head -n $(wc -l | sed -E -e 's/\s//g')
```

fails is that `wc` consumes all of the input and there is nothing left for `head` to see.  `wc` inherits its stdin from the subshell in which it is running, which is reading from the output of the `echo`.  Once it consumes the input, it returns and then `head` tries to read the data...but it is all gone.  If you want to read the input twice, the data will have to be saved somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @William. I could use `sed`, but in this question, I'm specifically trying to understand why the approach using `head` doesn't work.

Comment: +1 Why on Earth was this downvoted? The `sed` script is absolutely the correct, portable solution, and I find no flaw in the explanation.

Comment: The downvote was reasonable.  It occurred when the answer was nothing but the `sed` solution which did not address the question at all.

Comment: @aerijman `\$d` is another way of writing `'$d'`.  The `$` addresses the last line, and the command `d` is applied to that line.  That is, it deletes the last line.

Comment: On Windows use `sed $d` (no need to escape `$`).

Comment: @aerijman `sed` is not very good at addressing lines from the end of the file.  With gnu head (from coreutils 8.30) you can do `head -n -$n` (eg, `head -n -5` to see all but the last 5 lines).

Answer (score 103):

`head -n -1` will give you all except the last line of its input.

Comment: If you happen to be using a `head` that supports that syntax.  Not all do.

Comment: Thanks @dunc123. But I added a clarification that I don't have support for `head -n -1`.

Answer (score 14):

Using sed:

```
sed '$d' filename
```

will delete the last line of the file.

```
$ seq 1 10 | sed '$d' 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: At difference from the `head` solutions shown, this `sed` method works on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 10):

For Mac OS X specifically, I found an answer from a [comment to this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11834956/135157).

Assuming you are using Homebrew, run `brew install coreutils` then use the `ghead` command:

```
cat myfile.txt | ghead -n -1
```

Or, equivalently:

```
ghead -n -1 myfile.txt
```

Lastly, see `brew info coreutils` if you'd like to use the commands without the `g` prefix (e.g., `head` instead of `ghead`).

Answer (score 6):

```
cat myfile.txt | echo $(($(wc -l)-1))
```

This works. It's overly complicated: you could just write `echo $(($(wc -l)-1)) <myfile.txt` or `echo $(($(wc -l <myfile.txt)-1))`. The problem is the way you're using it.

```
cat myfile.txt | head -n $(wc -l | sed -E -e 's/\s//g')
```

`wc` consumes all the input as it's counting the lines. So there is no data left to read in the pipe by the time `head` is started.

If your input comes from a file, you can redirect both `wc` and `head` from that file.

```
head -n $(($(wc -l <myfile.txt) - 1)) <myfile.txt
```

If your data may come from a pipe, you need to duplicate it. The usual tool to duplicate a stream is `tee`, but that isn't enough here, because the two outputs from `tee` are produced at the same rate, whereas here `wc` needs to fully consume its output before `head` can start. So instead, you'll need to use a single tool that can detect the last line, which is a more efficient approach anyway.

Conveniently, sed offers a way of matching the last line. Either printing all lines but the last, or suppressing the last output line, will work:

```
sed -n '$! p'
sed '$ d'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner that can get you the desired output, and it can be used more generally for getting all lines from a file except the last n lines.

```bash
grep -n "" myfile.txt \ # output the line number for each line
| sort -nr \            # reverse the file by using those line numbers
| sed '1,4d' \          # delete first 4 lines (last 4 of the original file)
| sort -n \             # reverse the reversed file (correct the line order)
| sed 's/^[0-9]*://'    # remove the added line numbers
```

Here is the above command in an actual single line and runnable (can't execute the above due to the added comments):

```bash
grep -n "" myfile.txt | sort -nr | sed '1,4d' | sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9]*://'
```

It's a little cumbersome, and this problem can be solved with more comprehensive commands like `ghead`, but when you can't or don't want to download such tools, it's nice to be able to do this with the more basic options. I've been in situations where it's simply not an option to get better tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>1{print p}{p=$0}'
```

For this job, an awk one-liner is a bit longer than a sed one.