# How to combine output of `git diff --name-status` and `git diff --stat` commands?

Tags: git, shell, diff

With `git diff --name-status` command I can see names of files with file status like this:

```
M       .bashrc
D       .ghc/.ghci.conf.un~
D       .ghc/ghci_history
M       .life
A       .profile
M       .spacemacs
```

With `git diff --stat` I can see statistics of line count and file changes:

```
 .bashrc             |   3 ++-
 .ghc/.ghci.conf.un~ | Bin 13912 -> 0 bytes
 .ghc/ghci_history   | 100 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 .life               |   2 ++
 .profile            |  23 +++++++++++++++++++++
 .spacemacs          |   3 +++
```

Is there any way to combine outputs of both commands? I would like to have something like this:

```
M  .bashrc             |   3 ++-
D  .ghc/.ghci.conf.un~ | Bin 13912 -> 0 bytes
D  .ghc/ghci_history   | 100 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
M  .life               |   2 ++
A  .profile            |  23 +++++++++++++++++++++
M  .spacemacs          |   3 +++
```

Sure, I can do it manually by string calling both command and then manipulating strings. But I'm not sure how reliable and consistent outputs for these commands. Maybe it's documented somewhere. Could you, please, provide a shell command that will allow me to see such diffs from the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bash
DIFF=origin/master..HEAD
join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 \
        <(git diff --name-status $DIFF | sort -k2)
        <(git diff --stat=$((COLUMNS-4)),800 $DIFF | sed -e '$d' -e 's/^ *//;s/ /\t/' | sort) \
        | sed 's/\t/ /g'
```

Or, fully POSIX in an `[alias]` section of `~/.gitconfig`

```
ndiff = "!f() { TAB=`printf '\t'`; COLUMNS=`stty size|cut -d' ' -f2`; cd $GIT_PREFIX; git diff --name-status $1 | sort -k2 > /tmp/.tmpgitndiff ; git diff --stat=$COLUMNS,800 $1 |sed -e '$d' -e \"s/^ *//;s/ /${TAB}/\" | sort | join -t \"${TAB}\" -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 /tmp/.tmpgitndiff - | sed \"s/${TAB}/ /g\"; rm -f /tmp/.tmpgitndiff; }; f"
```

```
$ git ndiff origin/master..HEAD -- dev/ # example
M dev/main.scss   |   9 +
A dev/rs.js       |  19 ++
```

Comment: Should use something like `local temp_file=$(mktemp)` instead of hard-coding a filename which breaks multiple use.

Comment: I've tried to execute both commands from my shell but none of them seems to work correctly.

Comment: @Shersh: ensure you're running *bash* (for the first command) and not a stripped-down POSIX shell like busybox.

Comment: I've figured out why I had the problem. I'm using macOS. And I need to use `$'...'` strings everywhere I want to use `\t` character. Now the solution with `join` works and the output is quite lovely! I will test it more.

Comment: To make it work for all cases, you also need to `sort -k1` the result of `git diff --stat`. Otherwise, it doesn't always work for me. But at least I can have a single command that works on both macOS and Ubuntu, and this is fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

The quick-and-dirty was is to use `wdiff`:

```
$ wdiff -n -w '' -x '' -y '' -z '' <(git diff --name-status) <(git diff --stat)
vvv 2018-06-26 10:08:27-0700
M       foo/baz.py   | 19 +++++++++++--------
M       foo/bar.py   | 37 ++++++++-----------------------------
M       foo/qux.py   |  2 +-
 3 files changed, 20 insertions(+), 38 deletions(-)
```

The `-[w-z]` options set the delimiters for start/end of insertion/deletion.

`-n` ensures that output is linewise ... which probably doesn't matter when `-[w-z]` are passed, but is a good habit for `wdiff` in general.

Theoretically, this is prone to error if your filename looks like anything else on the line. Fortunately, good practice tends to eschew filenames like `M`, `|`, `19`, and `+++++++++++--------`

---

The more correct way would be to use `paste`, but that would require passing the output through `sed` afterward to remove the duplicate parts.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a for loop to filter the output for each possible status:

```
for filter in A C D M R T U X B; do git diff --diff-filter="$filter" --stat | head -n -1 | sed "s/.*/$filter &/"; done;
```

- `--diff-filter` makes sure that only files for the current status are shown (e.g. only [A]dded files)
- `--stat` shows the status you want
- the `head` command then removes the last line for each stat output (e.g. `x files changed, n deletions`)
- finally the `sed` command inserts the current filter at the start (e.g. `A`)

This does mean you always get the files sorted by their status and not by how they would have been sorted by the git command alone.

### Edit

As mentioned by @Shersh in the comments, `tail -n` does not work with negative integers on macOS. There are two solutions to this:

1. Either install ghead: `brew install coreutils` (credits to jchook's comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834899/tail-inverse-printing-everything-except-the-last-n-lines/11834956#comment-62096573))
2. Or use `tac` to reverse the lines, start from the second line with `tail -n +2` and then reverse again with `tac`:

```
for filter in A C D M R T U X B; do git diff --diff-filter="$filter" --stat | tac | tail -n +2 | tac | sed "s/.*/$filter &/"; done;
```

Ps. instead of `tac` you could also use `tail -r`, but this doesn't work on all systems, and you loose alignment (see @Shersh's comment, couldn't test on my system).

Comment: I see the following error when there is no output for some filter: `head: illegal line count -- -1`

Comment: Hmm.. That doesn't happen when I run it. Can you try to add `2>/dev/null` at the end of the `head` command? So, like this `head -n -1 2>/dev/null |`

Comment: Indeed, I don't see the error on my Ubuntu. The error was on macOS. I will try this trick on macOS then.

Comment: I've figured out why I saw the error on macOS. `head` on macOS doesn't support negative arguments. So I had to use the _tail reverse trick_ described in this question to make it work on both systems: unix.stackexchange.com/a/169080/359940 I think your solution is excellent and the easiest one. However, it doesn't provide alignment by `|`...

Comment: The easiest thing to do then is to use ghead on Mac OS X (installed via `brew install coreutils`, credits go to jchook, comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834899/tail-inverse-printing-everything-except-the-last-n-lines/11834956#comment-62096573)). You will keep your alignment and keep the command (relatively) simple. I will edit my answer accordingly.